# SSH error from Putty with EC2 private AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, rhel

I have been passed a few private AMI's (created from RHEL AMI's) with a view to spin up clones of these EC2 servers in another VPC

So launched new instances from these AMI's and used an exiting PEM key that is being used on other RHEL servers in the VPC. Can SSH into these existing servers just fine via Putty from Windows using the ppk converted by PuttyGen

However when i try and SSH into the new instances launched from the AMI i get two errors. Firstly when using ec2-user@172.x.x.x i get a key not found error. Then when using root@172.x.x.x i see this

Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key" from agent
Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!

Any ideas why this is? I tried creating a new image from a volume snapshot but still get same error. Seen some notes on editing the ssh/authorisedkeys file but cant even login to the server to get that. I could i guess spin up an SSH bastion and try and try it from there using the public key ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have connection then you don't need bastion. 
Try to re-create AMI (not from volume but from instance) assuming you do have root access to the instance the AMI should be created from. You'll have better chances if you stop the instance before making AMI.